# Tailwind CSS, React and Styled Components setup to load images on different break points

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components

I am learning Tailwind with Styled Components using twin macros. I have a very simple component with an image and description.

I want to have two breakpoints at which the image will change. At the moment I am having issues with loading any image from `tailwind.config.js`.

```
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "product-desktop": "url('../public/images/image-product-desktop.jpg')",
        "product-mobile": "url('../public/images/image-product-mobile.jpg')",
      },
    },
    screens: {
      md: "375px",
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }
      xl: "800px",
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }
    },
    fontFamily: {
      montserrat: ["font-family", "Montserrat", "sans-serif"],
      fraunces: ["font-family", "Fraunces", "sans-serif"],
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**ProductCard.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  CardContainer,
  CardDescriptionProduct,
  CardDescriptionContainer,
  CardDescriptionTile,
  CardDescription,
  CardDescriptionButton,
  CardDescriptionPrice,
  CardDescriptionStrikethrough,
  CardImage,
} from "./styles/Card.styled";
import { ReactComponent as ShoppingCartIcon } from "../assets/images/icon-cart.svg";

export const ProductCard = () => {
  return (
    <CardContainer>
      <CardImage></CardImage>
      <CardDescriptionContainer>
        <CardDescriptionProduct>Perfume</CardDescriptionProduct>
        <CardDescriptionTile>
          Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum
        </CardDescriptionTile>
        <CardDescription>
          A floral, solar and voluptuous interception composed by Oliver Polge,
          Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.
        </CardDescription>
        <div className="flex">
          <CardDescriptionPrice>$149.99</CardDescriptionPrice>
          <CardDescriptionStrikethrough>$169.99</CardDescriptionStrikethrough>
        </div>
        <CardDescriptionButton>
          <ShoppingCartIcon />
          Add to Cart
        </CardDescriptionButton>
      </CardDescriptionContainer>
    </CardContainer>
  );
};
```

**Card.styled.js:**

```
[![export const CardContainer = styled.div`
  ${tw`
    flex
    flex-col
    justify-center
    items-center
    h-full
  `}

  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 200px 30px;
  }
`;

export const CardImage = styled.div`
  ${tw`
    md:bg-product-mobile xl:bg-product-desktop
    w-10/12
    overflow-hidden
    mt-20
    rounded-t-lg
  `}
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0rem;

    min-height: 50vh;
  }
`;

export const CardDescriptionContainer = styled.div`
  ${tw`
    w-10/12
    bg-white
    rounded-b-lg
    p-5
  `}

  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 50vh;
  }
`;][1]][1]
```

In the above code, I know that `@media` is wrong, but could not find how to accomplish this the Tailwind way. It's just to show what I am trying to do.

IN this image i can see that the correct images are being loaded per break point but the just do not appear.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Looks like the path for the image set in `tailwind.congig.js` is wrong but i makes no sense to me unless i don't understand something
`url(images/image-product-desktop.jpg`) but if the tailwinf.config.js is in the root of the directory, and the images are is `src/assets/images` how could that be the right path. Also when i add the this path in config `images/image-product-desktop.jpg` tailwind will throw an error `Can't resolve the path`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Tailwind, you need to specify the breakpoint as a prefix. In this case you should leave your mobile image as the default and add the `xl` prefix to any class you want applied when the width >= 1440px.

```js
export const CardImage = styled.img`
  ${tw`
    bg-image-product-mobile xl:bg-image-product-desktop
  `}
`;
```

Since your background image appears to be added to the DOM, you might ensure that the path, `/src/images/image-product-desktop.jpg`, is pointing to the file correctly.

The image paths in your config should be relative to the static assets folder that your webserver uses, not relative to the `tailwind.config.js` file. Your server should find the desktop image if it's defined in your config as `/images/image-product-desktop.jpg` and the image file is placed in `/public/images`

Comment: I have modified my code mainly as suggested, good thing is that i can see the correct Image classes being loaded per break point the bad thing is I still cannot see  the image on the page

Comment: I can also see the images change in the network tab when i resize the screen

Comment: Please see my addition above.